# I need a delete button

Tags: keyboard

I also have an azerty keyboard, but am used to the qwerty and I want to know how I can modify the keyboard to have a "delete" function. Deleting using the backspace is laborious and I miss being able to delete from the front of the text. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

If you have an Apple keyboard: <kbd>fn-Backspace</kbd> is a substitute for <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Depending on the application <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> works as well.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) to remap CapsLock to delete.